# PHP DateTime Diff error I cannot figure out

Tags: php

Live server running PHP 5.3.27
Under root `www` directory I have the old site running.
Under `root/mysite` I have the new site running with zero errors or warnings.

I changed a staged WordPress site under the `subdirectory /mysite` using the index and `.httaccess` to be viewable using `www.example.com` instead of the staged `www.example.com/mysite`  I made the proper changes to site_url as well and the sites home page loads perfectly.

Under a separate page that calculates date ranges I get a Fatal Error stating:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::diff()...
```

When I switch the site back to the subdirectory and load it using `www.example.com/mysite/` no Fatal Error and the diff calculates the date ranges properly.

Again I'm running php 5.3.27.  I even switched it to 5.4 to verify and received a `mktime()` error that was corrected to `time()`, but still got the Fatal error on diff

Here's the code bit that is causing the problem:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($mysqlExpireDate);
$date2 = new DateTime();
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);  // ERRORS??
$days = $interval->days;
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, I've checked everything I can think of.

Comment: How about the procedural `date_diff()` function, eg `$interval = date_diff($date1, $date2)`? Can you also print out (from this same script) `phpversion()`?

Comment: Ensure that both $date1 and $date2 are being set correctly. Does $mysqlExpireDate provide the right format for DateTime and does instantiating a new DateTime mean it's timestamp is now?

Comment: @Dwight: it wouldn't explain **fatal** error, regardless of the object's properties values - it should provide the declared contract

Comment: @Phil you are a genius:  date_diff was previously tested and returned same error... BUT  phpversion() echos 5.4.19 to subdirectory and 5.2.17 to root.  Why the heck would this happen?  Host states 5.4 is loaded.

Comment: @William Hagan: what was it?

Comment: @Dwight:  yes sir $date1 & $date2 are okay.  $mysqlExpireDate is in a mysql format appropriate for the database and instance of DateTime() does create a now() datetime.

Comment: @zerkms:  echoed phpversion() from staged subdirectory yields 5.4.19 ( what my host php states ), BUT echoed phpversion() using same script from root yeilds 5.2.17!  Why and how does this happen?  How do I fix it?

Comment: @William Hagan: ask the hosting support or your sysadmin?

Comment: @WilliamHagan *"Genius"* might be a bit of a stretch. Glad to help though

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any autoloader?
may be it refers to any implemented class named DateTime.

Try changing `new DateTime` to `new \DateTime` or add `use \DateTime;` to beginning of your script.

You can check this using [`ReflectionClass::isUserDefined`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isuserdefined.php)